# WP8 WebBrowser how to find out type of navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have added a WebBrowser control on a page. If the user taps on any link in the WebBrowser I need to get the Uri of the request and load it in a new page. Im using WebBrowser class's Navigating event to get the url that is requested. To achieve what I need to do, I need to differentiate whether the navigation happens because of a link is clicked or by calling Navigate method or any redirection has happened. In iOS UIWebViewDelegate's shouldStartLoadWithRequest method passes UINavigation type as one of the arguments. This argument says whether the link is clicked or something else has happened like initial load or some redirection. How to find out this in WP8 WebBrowser control ?.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible. I think you'd have to inject some JS trickery to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

As mztan said there is no inbuilt way to detect the url click on a WebBrowser control in Windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

Set a Navigating event to the WebBrowser and NavigatingEventArgs(argument) gives you the uri which have to be converted to string.Check the below Code.

```
 private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
      string val = e.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It is obvious that NavigatingEventArgs gives the url requested as I already mentioned in the question itself. How to check the type of the navigation is WHAT MY QUESTION.